# MDI child not maximizing on create

Tags: forms, delphi

I have a MDI child form that when opening doesn't maximize at once.
I can see that the datagrid on it is created and then the form is maximized

I use the following constructor to create the form.

```
Properties:
FormStyle = fsMDIChild
Position = poDefaultPosOnly
WindowState = wsMaximized

constructor TfrmJsContacts.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
begin
  WindowState := wsMaximized;
  inherited Create(aOwner);
  TimerDelay.Enabled := True;
end;
```

The problem is a visual problem so to speak - everything works as it should. It just looks wrong that the form is shown before it is maximized. What really could be nice was to have a AfterShow event to play with. I think that would help me in this situation.

Comment: Why don't you wait until the form is showing, maximised, and then spend the time doing the grid data fetch?

Comment: All data is first fetched when the timer runs out so it shouldn't be the problem.  But I will test with a bigger timerinterval.

Comment: In that case I don't understand your problem. Perhaps somebody else will. Or maybe the question could be clarified.

Comment: It's a visual problem so to speak - everything works as it should. It just looks wrong that the form is shown before it is maximized. I really need a AfterShow event to play with. I think that would help me in this situation.

Comment: I still can't picture what the visual problem is. Never mind. Probably somebody else will be able to work it out.

Comment: Just create the window and set visible to false and when the timer expires and you loaded your data, set visible to true?

Comment: @whosrdaddy MDI children can't be invisible

Comment: mmm, forgot about that fact, has been ages ago that I made an MDI app :)

Comment: Its a bad idea to set form properties to do with display, inside the FormCreate event.  Some of these are ok to fiddle with in CreateParams.  Try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MDIChild popups comes with a little animation.

If MDIChild.Position is set to

- poDefaultPosOnly
- poDefaultSizeOnly
- poScreenCenter
- poDesktopCenter
- poMainFormCenter
- poOwnerFormCenter

Top and Left are calculated at creating

assume `Top` = 300 and `Left` = 400 now

at `on Show` MDIChild are now part of MDIParent and so

`Top` = 300 and `Left` = 400  are now Inside MDIParent.

Means left top corner of `MDIChild` is now in the middle of `MDIParent` form.

with `wsMaximized` the animation is shown from middle right to top left.

Now use Position

- poDesigned
- poDefault

and with Top and Left set to `0` the animation will not longer be seen.

```
constructor TfrmJsContacts.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
begin
  Top  := 0;
  Left := 0;
  WindowState := wsMaximized;
  inherited Create(aOwner);
  ....
end;
```

---

In Design mode when `frmJsContacts` is selected, go look at the Object Inspector.

- IF Property `WindowState` is set to `wsMaximized`

**You can see for a short time the whole form !**

If the changes are as follows, can be seen for a short time **only the title bar**, not the **whole form**.

- set, Object Inspector : Property `WindowState` to `wsNormal`.
- move code `WindowState := wsMaximized` below `inherited Create(aOwner)`.

code should like

```
constructor TfrmJsContacts.Create(aOwner: TComponent);
begin
  Top  := 0;
  Left := 0;
  inherited Create(aOwner);
  WindowState := wsMaximized;
  ....
end;
```

Comment: Thanks - now it is much better